# About C++ template

Tags: c++

I want to know how to understand below template definations. Could you explain to me?

```
// First, we define some factory functions for creating instances of
// the implementations.  You may be able to skip this step if all your
// implementations can be constructed the same way.

template <class T>
PrimeTable* CreatePrimeTable();

template <>
PrimeTable* CreatePrimeTable<OnTheFlyPrimeTable>() {
  return new OnTheFlyPrimeTable;
}

template <>
PrimeTable* CreatePrimeTable<PreCalculatedPrimeTable>() {
  return new PreCalculatedPrimeTable(10000);
}
```

I just know C  template function define like this:

```
template <Type A, Type B>
func(A a, B b) {
  //do some operation with a and b;
}
```

should it be the same as below definition?

```
template <class T>
PrimeTable* CreatePrimeTable(){
  return new T;
}
```

highly appreciate your help.

thanks

Comment: There's no such thing as a C template function (C has no templates). That's a C++ function template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is a forward declaration that tells the compiler that `PrimeTable* CreatePrimeTable<T>()` exists for all classes `T`.

```
template <class T>
PrimeTable* CreatePrimeTable();
```

Next is implementations/specialisations of the function for two possible types of T. Note, for complete specialisation/implementation of the non-generic case you remove the template parameters from the `template` part, resulting in the `template<>` before each function.

```
template <>
PrimeTable* CreatePrimeTable<OnTheFlyPrimeTable>() {
  return new OnTheFlyPrimeTable;
}

template <>
PrimeTable* CreatePrimeTable<PreCalculatedPrimeTable>() {
  return new PreCalculatedPrimeTable(10000);
}
```

This means that code like this will compile and work

```
PrimeTable* table1 = CreatePrimeTable<PreCalculatedPrimeTable>();
PrimeTable* table2 = CreatePrimeTable<OnTheFlyPrimeTable>();
```

And (unfortunately) this will compile, but fail to link, since there is no implementation of `CreatePrimeTable<int>()`.

```
PrimeTable* table3 = CreatePrimeTable<int>();
```

Comment: can this implemetation relace above? 
`template <class T>
PrimeTable* CreatePrimeTable(){
  return new T;
}`

Comment: That will not do the same thing at all